# Order posts by last comment date in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a combination of `get_comments()` and `get_post()` to display a list of posts ordered by comment date.

Ref:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

**My code:**

```
$args = array(
    'status' => 'approve',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$comments = get_comments( $args );

foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {

     $post = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );
     echo $post->post_title;

}
```

The problem with this approach is the list of posts will contain duplicate post titles if a post has more than one comment.

How can I remove the duplicates?

**UPDATE:**
This initial approach does a lot of unnecessary legwork. For example, on sites that have lots of posts and comments, the query will pull back lots of unnecessary comments.

**UPDATED QUESTION:**
How can I order a list of posts by comment date?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting approach...but, I suppose you could just fill an array with post ID's and then check them later.

```
$args = ....
$ids = array();
.....
if(!in_array($post->ID, $ids):
    $ids[] = $post->ID;
    echo $post->title;
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Ohgodwhy, `in_array()` looks to be the solution! Out of interest, would you recommend an alternative approach altogether then, or you think I should stick with my initial approach?

Comment: You got me thinking about my initial approach. I'm actually thinking it does a lot of unnecessary legwork. On sites that have *lots* of posts and comments, the query will be pulling back lots of unnecessary comments. I'm now thinking simply *how can I order a list of posts by comment date?*